# Recoger el height de elementos nativos de Ionic al cargar la vista

Tags: angular, ionic, angular7, ionic4, angular8

Necesito recoger la altura de un elemento justo cuando se carga la vista. Se trata de un elemento que su altura va a estar variando por lo que no siempre tendrá la misma altura. Mi problema viene al intentar recoger su altura justo al cargar la vista pero me viene en este caso en 0 a no ser que ponga un setTimeOut.

Una solución que me sirvió pero quiero evitarlo a toda costa es esta dentro del ciclo de vida ngAfterViewInit.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const height = document.getElementById('elemento').offsetHeight;
      }, 500);
}
```

En el html:

```
<ion-grid id="elemento">
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
        <\ion-col>
    <\ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

No siempre funciona ya que en varias ocasiones no me da la altura correctamente ya que si miro por consola las dimensiones del elemento en ciertas ocasiones varían unos cuantos pixeles.
También he probado a recogerlo de esta manera:

```
@ViewChild('grid', { static: false }) elemento: ElementRef;

 ngAfterViewInit() {
     const height = this.elemento.nativeElement.offsetHeight
}
```

En el html:

```
<ion-grid #grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
        <\ion-col>
    <\ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

Me gustaría alguna recomendación para estos casos. Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de `ngAfterViewInit`, lee la propiedad `ionViewDidEnter`, que se ejecuta después de haber renderizado la vista.
Aquí tienes [más información sobre el ciclo de vida de las páginas Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/lifecycle) (en inglés).

```js
ionViewDidEnter() {
   const height = document.getElementById('toastButton').offsetHeight;
}
```